# Modifying VBA macro with a macro

Tags: vba, module, edit

- there are quite a few different excel macro files with a link that has been updated. Is there a way to modify a macro with a macro?
- This is what I have been able to find so far using CodeModule, find line where the link is at and then replace the whole line. I have this macro in one file, and I run it in a file that I want to change (later I may automate it to go through all files in a folder), but need to get it working first.
- One part that is confusing me, at which point does SL (starting line) gets changed?
- What are CodeModule columns? My link is say 35characters long, why is the column 35, should it not be 1?
- Is there a better way? Thanks

  ```
  Sub findLink()

     Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
     Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
     Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
     Dim FindWhat As String
     Dim SL As Long ' start line
     Dim EL As Long ' end line
     Dim SC As Long ' start column
     Dim EC As Long ' end column
     Dim Found As Boolean

     Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
     Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
     Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

     'find text to replace
     FindWhat = "https://www.abc.net.au/"

     With CodeMod

         SL = 1
         EL = .CountOfLines
         SC = 1
         EC = 255
         Found = .Find(target:=FindWhat, StartLine:=SL, StartColumn:=SC, _
             EndLine:=EL, EndColumn:=EC, _
             wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, patternsearch:=False)
         Do Until Found = False
         MsgBox CStr(SL)
             Debug.Print "Found at: Line: " & CStr(SL) & " Column: " & CStr(SC)
             EL = .CountOfLines
             SC = EC + 1
             EC = 255
             Found = .Find(target:=FindWhat, StartLine:=SL, StartColumn:=SC, _
                 EndLine:=EL, EndColumn:=EC, _
                 wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, patternsearch:=False)
         Loop

         'If Found Then
         Call .ReplaceLine(SL, "Link = ""https://www.abc2.net.au/"" ")

     End With
      MsgBox "Found at: Line: " & CStr(SL) & " Column: " & CStr(SC)

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: _Is there a better way?_ - Put the link on a worksheet and get the code to reference it.  Much easier to update the value in a cell than change the VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

1. "*One part that is confusing me, at which point does SL (starting line) gets changed?*"

**When a match is found** it is returned/changed like **the line number on which the matching text is found**. Independent of its initial value. So, when trying to search from the beginning, **it is enough to only declare  the variable**.

And, in order to let the code searching the rest of the lines, you should increment **this returned line number/variable**:

So, you should replace:

```
SC = EC + 1
```

with:

```
SL = SL + 1 'to start searching from the next code line
```

2. "*What are CodeModule columns? My link is say 35characters long, why is the column 35, should it not be 1?*"

Well, "Each character in a code line **is in a separate column**, beginning with zero on the left code line side. If a match is found, the value of the `StartColumn` argument is set to the column in which the beginning character of the matching string is found.

So, if your code returns 35 (as `StartColumn`, after the match) it means that there are other 34 characters before the first one of the link string. Space characters are also counted...

If the respective code line contains other words which should be kept, the code may be adapted to change only the necessary string.

And, if there are more occurrences, your code (without the above suggested modification) will return only the first one. After modification, the final `MsgBox` will return only **the last occurrence**...

Comment: @nki8 Didn't the above answer clarify the issues in discussion? If not, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

Comment: thanks for your answer. Are you saying that Find is replacing SL value? I would think that I need to write something like SL +=1 inside the loop, or use Found.CountLines or Target.Row... Is SL not independent variable from Find function?
The reason I ask, this is where I stumble the most when coding, things happen on their own. Like the other day my date changed to 2021-01-01 00:00:00, it was quite difficult to return it to original 01/01/2021.

Comment: @nki8 This is what Microsoft says about the issue... This is VBA, not C. I already showed in the above answer how the incrementation must be done: `SL = SL + 1` instead of `SC = EC + 1`, which does not make any sense. "my date changed" has a general meaning and I do not understand what you mean. If you talk about a format cell in Excel, it is easy to be solved. If is it about the Windows date format, you probably played with Regional Settings. Didn't you try the above answer suggestion?

Comment: @nki8 On the other hand, didn't my above answer clarify your questions? If so, we here, when somebody answer our question in a useful way, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the answer is correct...